# How is better to manage data details (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to do a little list of data in TableView, and a DetailView.User tap on cell and goes to DetailView. In DetailView I have to check, what kind of data user selected in TableView. I pass name of data (title of cell) and Index(by prepareForSegue method). I can check name of data by two ways: by index, or by name (by switch). Which Way is better. My code for IndexCheck is something like this:

```
let Details = ["first","second","third"]
var PassedIndex:Int


override func ViewDidLoad () {
super.ViewDidLoad()
self.DetailLabel.text = Details[PassedIndex]
}
```

And a check by name is something like this:

```
var PassedName:String?
var DetailText:String
switch PassedName {

case "NumberOne":
                  DetailText = "#1"
case "NumberTwo":
                  DetailText = "#2"
case "NumberThree":
                  DetailText = "#3"
default:
                  DetailText  = "Unknown number"

}

 override func ViewDidLoad () {
super.ViewDidLoad()
self.DetailLabel.text = DetailText
}
```

Which way is the best? Which makes system working faster? I am just a beginner, so I need an advice from more experienced programmer than I

Comment: so you want to pass data using prepareForSegue() to another ViewController

Comment: @Lamar No, I have already done it, but I don't know which way to check the name passed is better

Comment: @Lamar Or, maybe it is more ways to solve it

Comment: check which named :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way of your two methods to check `Details` is check-by-index method. Why? Because it takes O(1) to take value that you need. Check by `String` takes O(n) in the worst case. But i suggest you to create an `Enum` that contains your `Details` and pass exactly detail that you need.